# How to fix Import Error raised by Docker Compose in a CI tool?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci-runner

I had to change `services: docker` in GitLab-CI.yml file to `services: docker:19.03.5-dind` because I was dealing with some compatibility issues but now GitLab-CI runner is having problems with importing `enum` for Python 2.7 within the container:

```
Running after script...
00:01
$ docker-compose down
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 7, in <module>
from compose.cli.main import main
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 35, in <module>
from ..project import get_image_digests
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/project.py", line 11, in <module>
import enum
ImportError: No module named enum
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

This is my GitLab-CI.yml file:

```
image: docker:stable

services:
  - docker:19.03.5-dind

stages:
  - build

before_script:
  - export REACT_APP_USERS_SERVICE_URL=http://127.0.0.1

compile:
  stage: build
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache py-pip python-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev gcc libc-dev make
    - pip install docker-compose
    - docker-compose up -d --build
    - docker-compose exec -T users python manage.py recreate_db
    - docker-compose exec -T users python manage.py seed_db
    - docker-compose exec -T users python manage.py test
    - docker-compose exec -T users flake8 project

after_script:
  - docker-compose down
```

It's quite obvious that Docker is trying to pull Python's `enum` module to perform certain tasks and fails. What should I do to resolve this ?

**Edit:**

I've added `python3-dev` to the build script to make it read like this

```
- apk add --no-cache py-pip python-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev gcc libc-dev make
```

surprisingly that didn't help either. Same error.

Comment: My Py2.7 Travis builds just started failing today for the same reason.

Comment: Really ??? Docker core devs are clearly working on some improvements but introduced a bug in the process. I'm pretty sure someone already raised an issue.

Comment: Some have solved this by `pip install enum34` but that didn't help me.

Comment: Agreed, that didn't help me either

Comment: And its now working for me again.

Comment: You're right. My build passed on GitLab runner as well. They fixed the bug whatever it was.